# How can I set videos in an iPad app to download the first time, then play from a saved local version every time after?

Tags: xcode, caching, video, video-streaming, multimedia

I have a ton of video in this app I'm designing, and I want to come in under the 20meg limit for the initial download, but I would love to have the thing work for folks when they don't have access to WIFI/3G. I want to have the video stream in and download the first time it's viewed, but then be saved and play from the local file every time afterward.

Anybody done something like this before? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic way for caching could be done as follows: When you want to see a video, first see if it is in the cache.If it is there already then load it from the cache. Otherwise download it and save it in the cache. You can use the video URI (or its hash) as the file-name when you save it in the storage. Implementing File operations won't be a big problem as there are lots of resources out there to help you. You might want to create a utility class for handling all the caching operations.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have sort of concluded that there's no way to let it download each vid once and eventually make it 100% offline. Now I'm leaning toward simply using YouTube as it's free.